# The ';' character in the input is being misinterpreted

Tags: c, shell

I wrote a program to split an input string using ';' as the terminator and print the part of the string that is after ';'. The program shows correct output whenever substring following ';' in the input string is not a valid terminal command but also prints `command not found`. On the other hand, it does not prints anything when the substring followed by ';' is a valid terminal command and executes the substring as a command , e.g. in case input "sjhjh;ls" it will execute ls command.

How do I get rid of the `command not found` part? 
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char * input;
    char * str;
    char * word;
    char terminator = ';';

    if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no string provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }

     input = argv[1];
     word = strchr(input, terminator);
     if (word != NULL) printf("%s\n", word);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Guys, don't downvote this question. It's actually a quite rare and interesting example of interplay between the shell and an application.

Comment: suggest adding the name of the shell as a tag

Comment: @DYZ I won't downvote, but its actually an example of not using the debugger or not creating an MCVE. Otherwise it would be clear, that the text never reaches the `argv` in main and the question could have a completely different focus.

Comment: @grek40 Fair enough. But I find it more educating the way it is.

Comment: OP, please listen to @grek40. Get yourself an IDE like MS Visual Studio community edition, Eclipse CDT, Code::Blocks, etc.  You can set  `breakpoint`s anywhere in your code and, as you debug, the program will stop at the breakpoint. When it does, you can look at the call stack and the value of your variables (you can also change their values), and more. If you do not use an IDE, you give yourself an unnecessary handicap. If you do, you won't need to ask so many questions here ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you execute your program like:

```
your_program_name sjhjh;ls
```

on the command line, you actually invoke *two* programs. The first is `your_program_name sjhjh` (so, `argv[1]` is `"sjhjh"`), and the second is `ls`. What you need is to make sure that the rest of the command line goes unparsed by the shell, and this is accomplished by properly quoting it:

```
your_program_name 'sjhjh;ls'
```

Comment: Also, the OP could tighten the code a little, by changing `if (argc < 2)` to `if (argc != 2)`, which would have shown the error. After all, the code does not cater fro more than a single parameter. An equality check would therefore have been better. @Romy, as you can see, just being more precise with your code can detect error for you, even avoid them. Ask your self, as you write each line of code, "what, exactly, am I trying to achieve here?"

Comment: @Mawg hold your horses, the `argc` check would not reveal anything, because `argv[1]` would be shorter (not containing ';' and following text) but it would still exist with the text before the first ';'

Comment: You got me! (+1) Still the check would catch spaces, and, while it doesn't catch this error, it is certainly slightly better code. The main point though, as you pointed out, is to learn to use a debugger.